# DOMDocument doesn't work on my variable, but it does if I add the HTML to the variable directly in the file

Tags: feeds

I'm using `mod_feed`.  I'm calling in an RSS feed from the Joomla! security strike team http://feeds.joomla.org/JoomlaSecurityNews.  I want to show certain parts of that feed on our Joomla! User Group site.

The variable is `$text` and echoing that fires out some HTML.  That is the default action of `mod_feeds`.  If I copy and paste the outputted HTML it works well.  See below.

https://3v4l.org/O3AbL

As soon as I use `$text` it stops working.  But if I then copy the HTML into the file and set that as `$text` it works.

Why won't it work with the HTML that Joomla! creates?

PHP

```
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        //$doc->loadHTML($text);
        @$doc->loadHTML($text);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
        $feed_items = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "newsfeed")]');

        foreach ($feed_items as $feed_item) {
            $impact_node = $xpath->query('*/li[contains(string(), "Impact:")]', $feed_item);
            $impact = preg_replace('/Impact:\W*/', '', $impact_node->item(0)->textContent);
            echo "Impact: " . $impact . "\n";
            $severity_node = $xpath->query('*/li[contains(string(), "Severity:")]', $feed_item);
            $severity = preg_replace('/Severity:\W*/u', '', $severity_node->item(0)->textContent);
            echo "Severity: " . $severity . "\n";
        }
```

Comment: Are you able to sniff out what is causing the breakage? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759069/2943403  have you inspected the text with `var_dump()` to see if there is any hidden characters?  Have you tried `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` (ex. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50407779/2943403)  Not a solution, but an alternative processing snippet: https://3v4l.org/R1A7i

Comment: I don't really understand what the `var_dump()` is doing to help me.  https://dev.joomlalondon.co.uk/ it's on this page at the moment.  I don't really know what I'm looking for.  I did `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`, again I don't know what to expect to see.  I had a look at the other posts, I set up the function suggested, that has changed nothing.  I tried your alternate syntax, still nothing I'm afraid.

Comment: There are no qualifying nodes in the `$text` that you are using.  IOW, no tag with the required class in your first first `xpath->query()`.  https://3v4l.org/uoaSJ  Do I misunderstand the point where `$text` is being declared/used?

Comment: Oh man, what an idiot!  Thanks!  The `.newsfeed` class is in the div before it.  MUPPET!

Comment: How shall we resolve this page then?  Do you want to retract or shall I try to answer?  I'm not fussed either way.  Did you perform a preparation step upon `$text` that is not shown?  You can of course answer if you wish.  You _are_ demonstrating some good DOMDocument and XPath techniques here.

Comment: I'm demonstrating some good copy and paste techniques here ha ha.  But I'm trying to learn.  Thanks for your help. you should answer it and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by your iterated `var_dump()` outputs on your dev page, the HTML strings that are in `$text` do not contain the class value required in your first `$xpath->query()`.

There are no generated errors, just a logical hiccup. The parent div that you expected was not included in the string -- so the `foreach()` is never entered.

This is one of your `$text` strings:

```
<ul>
<li><strong>Project:</strong> Joomla!</li>
<li><strong>SubProject:</strong> CMS</li>
<li><strong>Impact:</strong> Low</li>
<li><strong>Severity:</strong> <span class="label label-info">Low</span></li>
<li><strong>Versions:</strong> 3.8.0 - 3.9.13</li>
<li><strong>Exploit type:</strong> Path Disclosure</li>
<li><strong>Reported Date:</strong> 2019-November-22</li>
<li><strong>Fixed Date:</strong> 2019-December-17</li>
<li><strong>CVE Number:</strong> <a href="https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-19845">CVE-2019-19845</a></li>
</ul>
<h3>Description</h3>
<p>Missing access check in framework files could lead to a path disclosure.</p>
<h3>Affected Installs</h3>
<p>Joomla! CMS versions 3.8.0 - 3.9.13</p>
<h3>Solution</h3>
<p>Upgrade to version 3.9.14</p>
<h3>Contact</h3>
<p>The JSST at the <a title="Contact the JSST" href="https://developer.joomla.org/security-centre.html">Joomla! Security Centre</a>.</p>
<div class="alert alert-info"><strong>Reported By: </strong>Lee Thao, Viettel Cyber Security</div><div class="feedflare">
<a href="https://feeds.joomla.org/~ff/JoomlaSecurityNews?a=_fWsZ57Sw7g:uVTwWaDiNQ0:yIl2AUoC8zA"></a>
</div>
```

You can use my snippet below to process the html string: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XdsPJ))

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$impact_node = $xpath->query('//li[contains(string(), "Impact:")]');
echo "Impact: " . str_replace('Impact: ', '', $impact_node->item(0)->textContent);
echo "\n";
$severity_node = $xpath->query('//li[contains(string(), "Severity:")]/span[contains(@class, "label-info")]');
echo "Severity: " . $severity_node->item(0)->textContent . "\n";
```

Output:

```
Impact: Low
Severity: Low
```

Comment: But I still need to do a foreach on the `<ul>`.  is there a way to target the UL without a class?  I tried `$feed_items = $xpath->query('//ul');` and also `$feed_items = $doc->getElementsbyTagName("ul");`

Comment: Pass me the entire html string as a 3v4l demo and I'll parse the whole thing for you ...when I get a chance (just left Elton John).

Comment: Nice!  I assume you mean a concert and not his house :)  Actually now I look at it, the HTML you have just repeats.  I think the easiest way would be to append a containing div with a class, which I can do myself and use the existing code.  Woohoo.