# Module title is not showing despite setting module title to yes

Tags: module, overrides, feeds

I've created and overridden [a mod_feed](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/26659/12352) targeting the [Joomla! Security News Feed](http://feeds.joomla.org/JoomlaSecurityNews).

https://dev.joomlalondon.co.uk/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=g5_hydrogen:blog-news--bbc&id=55&Itemid=1334

For some reason the module title isn't showing even though I've set it to yes.

Is this controlled within the module?  I thought this was controlled outside of the module override in the schema.

If it's controlled within the module, I can't find anything that shows it.  I have checked other core modules and can't find it either.  If it's not controlled within the module, what could be my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it was me perhaps it was `mod_feed` (let's assume it was me.

This line was missing so I added it.

```
<?php if($module->showtitle){echo "<div class='g-content'><h2>" . $module->title . "</h2></div>";} ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using a Gantry template, which likely has pre-defined module positions.

In the Hydrogen template that you're using, the module position will be getting called like this:

`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="custom-position"/>`

Note there is no `type` value, therefore it'll use the default (inherited) style. This -- for some reason that I've never figured out nor delved too deeply into -- does not display module titles by default. So, you can either:

1. add a `type` value to your `jdoc:include` or
2. set the template in the module (under Advanced > Module Style) to use a style which does display the title. For example: "XHTML"